# TextMate Arduino Bundle Problems

Tags: macos, arduino, bundle, textmate

I'm trying to use this bundle with my textmate:
https://github.com/nasser/arduino.tmbundle

I've installed it successfully, but in a basic blink.ino sketch saved in my Desktop, when I try to Bundles > Arduino > Compile I get this pop-up in a separate window:

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w       -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=100 -I/Users/neiljohari/Desktop/Programming/Arduino/Blink -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/EEPROM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Esplora/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Ethernet/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Ethernet/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Ethernet/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Ethernet/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Ethernet/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Ethernet/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Firmata/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/GSM/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/LiquidCrystal/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Motor/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Motor/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Motor/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Motor/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/SD/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/SD/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/SPI/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Servo/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/SoftwareSerial/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Stepper/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/TFT/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/WiFi/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/WiFi/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/WiFi/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/WiFi/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Wire/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Ethernet/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Ethernet/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/SD/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/SD/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/SD/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/TFT/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/TFT/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/WiFi/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/WiFi/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/WiFi/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Robot_Control/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/TFT/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/WiFi/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Wire/utility/ -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/variants/standard -mmcu=atmega328p applet/Blink.cpp -o applet/Blink.o
applet/Blink.cpp:1:22: error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory
applet/Blink.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
applet/Blink.cpp:18: error: 'OUTPUT' was not declared in this scope
applet/Blink.cpp:18: error: 'pinMode' was not declared in this scope
applet/Blink.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
applet/Blink.cpp:23: error: 'HIGH' was not declared in this scope
applet/Blink.cpp:23: error: 'digitalWrite' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [applet/Blink.o] Error 1
```

And it didn't upload to my board. I understand none of that error, because I am used to the Arduino IDE, but I still do wish to use TextMate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem, here's how I did it:
First I created a new sketch using the Arduino IDE, and saved it where I wanted.

Then I deleted conflicting folders in the libraries Arduino uses, to get there from TextMate, you go: Bundles > Arduino > Open Arduino Libraries

From there you delete conflicting folders, first it complained about Esplora, so into the trash with that. Then RobotController and Motors, and then WiFI.

If anyone has a solution that doesn't require me deleting such libraries, please say so, but for now, this works just fine.